# Double external monitors on a iMac

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

Possible to use two externals? I know there is only one port in the back, but is there an adapter / way it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a USB->DVI adapter. I've never used one so I can speak for them.  http://sewelldirect.com/articles/usb-dvi-mac-drivers-tested-in-house.aspx

Comment: I like this idea, will have to keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Matrox DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/). According to [this](http://voice.firefallpro.com/2006/02/mac-mini-dual-monitors-using.html) article, it works under OSX.

> Simply put, this box acts as a splitter for a VGA signal. It effectively takes one VGA input, and splits each horizontal line in half, and feeds one half to one VGA output, and the other half to the (you guessed it) other VGA output. Unfortunately, according to Matrox, it’s only supported under Windows. Well, I’m happy to say that this jigger works great under OSX too.

In this case you'll need a VGA->DVI converter, but maybe theres a splitter for DVI also.